# float not working in dompdf laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I am create pdf file using dompdf but float property not working. I changed  DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT to true. It works fine in normal php  but its not working in laravel 4.

**Here is my code.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
.left {
  float: left; 
  outline: 1px solid green; 
  width: 6cm; 
}
.right {
  float: left; 
  outline: 1px solid blue; 
  width: 6cm; 
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="left" style="float:left;">left boxes here</div>
  <div class="right" style="float:right;">right boxes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the rest of the CSS loading correctly? You might try checking the float setting at runtime: `$dompdf->get_option('enable_css_float');`.

Answer (score 2):

use `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);` into the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file
and use the css float into your pdf design, it works

Comment: In Laravel `dompdf_config.inc.php` file not found

Comment: Add enable_css_float => true in laraveldompdf -> config -> dompdf.php